# Location of a certain method

Tags: java

So I have this program that is essentially a product inventory / store / shopping cart. The user enters a product number, and it is added to the cart, and that is pretty much it. The problem is that my driver contains a large percentage of the functional code. I want the section below to be in another class, but I don't know how to go about that. Any help?

```
if (entry == P0N) { //initial product number...must be as many as there are products
    System.out.println ("HOW MANY?");
    int cart = Keyboard.readInt();
    if (cart > P0Q) {
        System.out.println ("EXCEEDS AVAILABLE QUANITITY!\nPLEASE TRY AGAIN!"); //will send user to the main menu
    } else if (cart <= P0Q) {
        P0C += cart;
        P0Q -= cart;
        MyCart.add ("Gloves\t\t\t"+cart);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using Keyboard class on such a simple program, start with the basic Java API(ahem*Scanner*ahem).

Besides that, your little "program" here is not complex nor separate; I don't see why you need to place your code in a different class, you don't even need any classes other than the main one for this. just do this:

```
public class Inventory {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
    //declare your variables
    if (entry == P0N) { //initial product number...must be as many as there are products
    System.out.println ("HOW MANY?");
    int cart = Keyboard.readInt();
    if (cart > P0Q) {
        System.out.println ("EXCEEDS AVAILABLE QUANITITY!\nPLEASE TRY AGAIN!"); //will send user to the main menu
    } else if (cart <= P0Q) {
        P0C += cart;
        P0Q -= cart;
        MyCart.add ("Gloves\t\t\t"+cart);
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, my question may not have been clear. I already have a program that runs, and it has 7 classes total. This class, my driver, is a lot more complex than what I posted in the question. The part I posted was just the part that I wanted to move to another class, if possible.

Comment: You can easily move it to another class. Have you learned setter/getter methods? Make this program a method that returns void by doing public void myMethod { use different setter/getters to use variables that have been encapsulated.